# Excel Reverting from Shared drive to UNC path and then losing links

Tags: microsoft-excel, shared-folders, hyperlink, unc

Got an issue with a user getting the following error.

Random Excel sheets lose their links to other sheets on the shared drives. However when they lose their links they also revert from X:\Folders\Excel.xls to \Server\Folder\Folder\Excel.xls offline files are disabled and the user is on a desktop.

I'm aware of https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2808316/network-mapped-drive-hyperlinks-resolve-as-unc-in-office-products however this doesn't explain the links breaking.

The sheets effected seems to be random, and even after fixing the links, the issue can return to the same sheet and links.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are the hyperlinks attached to ? Cells or other objects ?

Comment: Cells from what I can make out. @PeterH